# Ubuntu install on corrupted windows machine

Tags: boot, software-installation, windows-7

I was working on linux for last 1 year and like linux more than Mac and Windows from my past experiences. Now I've my machine at home is windows 7, I was trying to expand the memory of local disk C, but it didn't went well. Now when I start my machine it is showing,

Rebook manager is missing
Alt Ctl and Alt to restart.

So as I was already planning to switch my machine to linux... I dont want Windows on my machine anymore. I would like to know whether I can install Linux directly without bothering the reboot manager, or do I need to fix this to install Linux.

I would like know the possible options in front of me to install Linux on my machine. And please point me a good post on how to install linux, as I'm very much new to installation.

Comment: If you install Ubuntu, the installer is very self explanatory. You will just need to burn the installation media on another machine, boot into the media and follow instructions. The installer will reformat the HDD for you.

Comment: The error message seems to be a windows problem, is it? If yes, go ahead and install over windows -- ubuntu does not care. But be sure to save all relevant data you want to keep. The Ubuntu installation is imho self-explanatory unless you want to create individual partitioning. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation are good descriptions of what you are doing and what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download an Ubuntu ISO (on a working computer) and burn it to dvd och create a bootelble USB. Make sure the that your BIOS is set to boot either from dvd or usb.
Ubuntu will take care of the rest.
(Assuming that you do not need to backup data from Windows. The install will ask you if you want to delete all files and turn your machine into Ubuntu-only)

Comment: How do I set to boot from usb?

Comment: When your start your computer, direct att the beginning, before Windows start, you wil see a message like: Pres <F2> to enter BIOS setup (could be something else than the <F2> button, sometimes it'e <DEL> or <F.......>). Then you search for something like "boot order". Make sure USB comes before Harddisk.